# Is it possible to integrate a leap motion controller with a google cardboard?

Tags: android, leap-motion, google-cardboard

Hi guys I would like to know if it is possible to integrate a leap motion controller with a google cardboard.

Comment: Do you mean integrating the software or the hardware? Integrating the hardware would take some glue and more paper.

Comment: To integrate the hardware I have a developer mount, the software is the problem since leap motion does not have support for android and cardboard works with android apps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is a semi-private alpha program for Android (see https://community.leapmotion.com/t/android-sdk-hardware-requirements/2845). Without the alpha SDK, you could run the tracking software on a PC and send the data to the Android device. (Obviously, this isn't a portable solution, but does allow experimentation.)

Comment: How can I send the data to the android device? i want to do something like this: https://www.leapmotion.com/product/vr, integrate a glass of VR to leap motion, for the oculus rift is perfect because the have fully support for leap motion integration, but with  the cardboard is different, I guess a hack is needed.

Comment: You have to send the data over the network. I think Node.js is a popular way to set up a server on the PC. If your app is browser-based, you can get the tracking data from the computer in JSON format using the WebSocket protocol. (This requires some config changes.) There's also a WebRTC plugin to Leap.JS (https://github.com/leapmotion/leapjs-network). So there are lots of way to do it.